# Iterate over a list and making a new row based on Thymeleaf template

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, foreach, thymeleaf

I'm iterating over my product list and setting the variables like this

```
List<InvoiceEntry> products = invoice.getProducts();

  for (InvoiceEntry product : products) {
      BigDecimal netValue = product.getProduct().getNetValue()
          .setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
      double vatRate = product.getProduct().getVatRate().getVatPercent();
      BigDecimal vatValue = netValue.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(vatRate))
          .setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
      long amount = product.getAmount();

      context.setVariable("productName",product.getProduct().getName());
      context.setVariable("amount", product.getAmount());
      context.setVariable("retailPrice", netValue + "zł");
      context.setVariable("productNetValue",
          netValue.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(amount)) + "zł");
      context.setVariable("productVatRate", (int) (vatRate * 100) + "%");
      context.setVariable("productVatValue",
          vatValue.multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(amount)) + "zł");
      context.setVariable("total",
          netValue.add(vatValue).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(amount)) + "zł");
    }

    String body = templateEngine.process("template", context);
    emailSender.sendEmail("someEmail@gmail.com", "some title", body);
    return "index";
```

the template snippet

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr bgcolor="D0D0D0">
    <td height="50" align="center"><h2 th:text="Name"></h2></td>
    <td height="50" align="center"><h2 th:text="Amount"></h2></td>
    <td height="50" align="center"><h2 th:text="RetailPrice"></h2></td>
    <td height="50" align="center"><h2 th:text="NetValue"></h2></td>
    <td height="50" align="center"><h2 th:text="VatRate"></h2></td>
    <td height="50" align="center"><h2 th:text="VatValue"></h2></td>
    <td height="50" align="center"><h2 th:text="Total"></h2></td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="ffffff">
    <td height="50" align="center"><h2 th:text="${productName}"></h2></td>
    <td height="50" align="center"><h2 th:text="${amount}"></h2></td>
    <td height="50" align="center"><h2 th:text="${retailPrice}"></h2></td>
    <td height="50" align="center"><h2 th:text="${productNetValue}"></h2></td>
    <td height="50" align="center"><h2 th:text="${productVatRate}"></h2></td>
    <td height="50" align="center"><h2 th:text="${productVatValue}"></h2></td>
    <td height="50" align="center"><h2 th:text="${total}"></h2></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The question is how can I create a new row of new elements without losing previous data?
for example, I want to achieve something like this
[image]

So far I'm still getting only the last element from the list because of overwriting.
 I'm pretty new in Thymeleaf so much appreciate every help and tip ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting each individual attribute, you put the product list on the model. Then use `th:each` to loop over it.

Controller

```
context.setVariable("products", products);
```

Template

```
<tr bgcolor="ffffff" th:each="product: ${products}">
  <td height="50" align="center"><h2 th:text="${product.product.name}"></h2></td>
  <td height="50" align="center"><h2 th:text="${product.amount}"></h2></td>
  .
  .
  .
</tr>
```